# What does "SAVED and set. (mismatch)" (and in particular the "mismatch" part) mean in emacs customize?

Tags: emacs, customization, dot-emacs

I was just trying to customize some `org-mode` export settings in emacs, and so I did <kbd>M-x</kbd><kbd>customize-group</kbd><kbd>org-export-html</kbd>.  This brought up by Customize buffer, and, among other things, I went about changing the `org-export-html-postamble-format` to something more to my liking.

Possibly relevant: During this process, I'd used a few <kbd>C-o</kbd>'s to open new lines, so the value would look nice to me on the screen, and I could tell what I was doing.  When satisfied, I clicked on the <kbd>State</kbd> button, and chose `Save for Future Sessions`.  Because (I presume) of the <kbd>C-o</kbd> newlines, it then said:

`CHANGED outside Customize; operating on it here may be unreliable. (mismatch)`

So, I then chose `Reset to Saved`, which got rid of that, but replaced it with this:

`SAVED and set. (mismatch)`

OK, so... all is well... except...  In both of those lines, what does `(mismatch)` mean?  That there's a mismatch between what's saved in my emacs init file and what I'm looking at?  That there's a mismatch between...  Well, looking around further, I even see some customize entries that say:

`STANDARD. (mismatch)`

Standard *and* mismatch?  (There are others which just say `STANDARD.`, by the way.)

I want to understand what "mismatch" means.  Any hints?

Thanks!

---

**Addenda**:

I just went digging a little in `cus-edit.el`, and found this in the comments:

```
;; 8. mismatch

;;    The widget value is not valid member of the :type specified for the
;;    option.
```

This helps, a little... does it just mean that `org-mode`'s type specifier is wrong?  Looking at that (in `org-html.el`), it specifies `:type 'string`, but in reality it seems to be a plist (even its default value is of the form `'(("en" "[data here]"))`.)  Is this just bad cleanliness on the part of `org-mode`?  But then, even another variable in here says "mismatch", but seems logically to have a value that makes sense.  The value is `t` (and I checked in my emacs init, and it's just the symbol `t`, no quotes or anything), and the type specifier for that is:

`:type '(choice (const :tag "No postamble" nil)
         (const :tag "Auto preamble" 'auto)
         (const :tag "Default formatting string" t)
         (string :tag "Custom formatting string")
         (function :tag "Function (must return a string)")))`

... which would seem to match that third line.  No?  Is `'(choice ...` not a valid value for `:type`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like two bugs:

- a trivial one in org-html.el which declares `:type 'string` for that variable, even though the variable's value is not a string.
- a bug in customize which says "changed outside customize" in this mismatched case, even though the mismatch actually came straight from customize and not outside of it.

Please report it with `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Answer (score 0):

> Because (I presume) of the C-o newlines, it then said:
>   CHANGED outside Customize; operating on it here may be unreliable. (mismatch)

I've never looked into the details, but I would assume that "CHANGED outside Customize" almost certainly means that somewhere in your config the `org-export-html-postamble-format` variable is set directly in code. The text of the error certainly doesn't suggest it could be caused if the variable was only ever set via the customize interface.

Comment: Well, that's the only way I ever changed this one.  Also, I can reproduce this, easily.  Just customize the variable, do a `C-o`, save, and I'll get that.  `Revert to Saved` gets the value back with all my hard-newlines replaced with `\n`.  Anyway, this was just an along-the-way step that I included in case it was relevant.  I'm pretty sure it's not.  Thanks, though.